# Adding link to the main help page

Tags: 8, hooks

I have created an help page for my module

```
function amu_hal_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'help.page.amu_hal':
       return 'some content';
  }
}
```

This does create a page at

> /fr/admin/help/amu_hal

How can add the correspondong link on main help page

> /fr/admin/help

Comment: Easiest always is to just look how other modules are doing it.

Comment: what if i did not find how ? can i still ask the question?

Answer (score 1):

i found out that the code above create automatically a link in the main help page, as long as the .info file indicate

> name: AMU HAL

and not

> name: 'AMU HAL'